# Unzip the multiple *.gz files and make one csv file in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am having multiple files in S3 bucket and have to unzip these files and merge all files into a single file(CSV) with single header. All files are contains same header.

The data files are looks like below.

Storage system : S3 bucket.

```
 part-0000-XXXX.csv.gz
 part_0001-YYYY.csv.gz
 part-0002-ZZZZ.csv.gz
 .
 .
 .
 .
 part-0010_KKKK.csv.gz.
```

I want one single CSV file from all the files as shown above. Please help me how to unzip and merge all the files.

After unzip and merging all files into a single CSV, then I can use this file for data comparison with previous files..

I am using spark 2.3.0 and scala 2.11

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code, also you can directly read from gz file without extracting:

```
val filePath = "/home/harneet/<Dir where all gz/csv files are present>"

var cdnImpSchema = StructType(Array(
 StructField("idate",     TimestampType, true),
 StructField("time",     StringType, true),
 StructField("anyOtherColumn",  StringType, true)
))

var cdnImpDF = spark.read.format("csv").     // Use "csv" regardless of TSV or CSV.
 option("delimiter", ","). // Set delimiter to tab or comma or whatever you want.
 schema(cdnImpSchema).        // Schema that was built above.
 load(filePath)

cdnImpDF.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("mydata.csv")
```

repartition(1) -> Will produce one file as output.

Answer (score 1):

Below Mentioned code seems to be working fine.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("/root/data")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /root/data MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24


scala> rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/root/combinedCsv", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
```

You can see the input data is in `/root/data` directory and combined csv in gzip format is stored in `/root/combinedCsv` directory.

**Update**

If you want to store data in csv format, strip off GzipCodec part.

```
scala> rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/root/combinedCsv")
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help. I want unzip the csv files for further comparison of data.

Comment: You can use `gunzip <file location>` to unzip the gz file. Alternately you can save the RDD in csv format by running `rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("/root/combinedCsv")`